# Facebook graph api group feed's post's "type" incorrect

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token

My ultimate goal is to be able to retrieve youtube links (if any) from all the posts in the closed group no matter who posted it.

I am able to read the all feeds of a closed group using my own access token. The token has the following permission:

1. user_about_me
2. user_activities
3. user_groups
4. user_events
5. read_stream

The problem is, when I post a youtube link into the group's feed MYSELF, I am able to see its "type" as "link". Thus, I am able to read the link field from the post and retrieve the correct youtube link.

BUT when other members of the group posts the same youtube link into the group's feed, using still my own access token (not his), graph api is telling me its "type" is "status" instead of "link". And in this case, link field of the post does not exist and I am not able to retrieve the youtube link from the post.

Any idea why this happens? Is it the nature of user access token and if so how can I solve this?